# Видеоуроки по MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Здравствуйте, ищу видеоуроки о MVC. Посмотрел 3 урока на сайте фирсов-алексей.рф, но это мало. Понравилось то, что все запросы обрабатываются через `index` файл. И вот, кто может искал и нашел уроки об этой теме (запросы через индекс), то рад буду слышать =)

Comment: Могу посоветовать уроки Гайдара Магданурова, но там на асп.нет.

Comment: я видел их, хочу без асп.нет =)

Comment: К сведению - все запросы через index файл это шаблон проектирования FrontController и его применение вовсе не обязательно в MVC.<br>
Просто во всех фреймворках 1а точка входа и нередко делаются вот такие вот выводы...<br>
А вообще в вашем случае просто зроровски было бы читнуть книгу <a href="http://progbook.net/php/5121-php-obekty-shablony-i-metodiki-programmirovaniya-2-e-izd.html">Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования</a>, я вам гарантирую не один видеоурок не заменит книгу

Comment: не люблю книги, но раз вы гарантируете то попробую почитать:)

Comment: В этой книге строго "мясо" + лично я ее в свое время использовал как справочник, т.е. ознакомился с шаблончиком, придумал себе задачу и сразу закреплять, ну и потом подсматривать если что, книга не напряжная, если я ее до сиих пор не снес - можете в этом не сомневаться ^^

Comment: >не люблю книги

тогда вам не в программисты, а пылесосами в Техносиле торговать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так Вы хотите научиться организовывать одну точку входа в программу или познакомиться с паттерном MVC? На самом деле неважно. Гуглите, гуглите и Вам воздастся)
Для затравки вот Вам примеры запросов:
- шаблон MVC PHP
- шаблоны проектирования/design patterns
- банда 4х
- ....

Из видео о том, о чем Вы спрашиваете есть [тут](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3675154) и вообще много где. Посморите там же курсы "Специалист PHP"

Comment: Не смотрите исходники CodeIgniter и прочей лабуды. Если уж идти этим путем, то смотрите Zend Framework

Comment: по гуглил почитал про zf, думаю это мое)) может есть у кого ссылки на видео уроки по Zend Framework, читать статьи не люблю))

Comment: с видео по zf не сталкивался. Вообще посмотрите на рутрэкере. Если там нет нужных Вам видео, см. гугл. если нет в гугле => нет в природе=)

Comment: а можно все это без zf сделать? я просто смотрел 3 урока по mvc [здесь](URL "http://фирсов-алексей.рф/Скрипты_Видеоуроки/Видеоуроки/function_для_работы_в_будушем_или_MVC_часть_3/") , и там zf не используется, но используется одна точка входа

Comment: разумеется. Я всегда одну точку входа делаю. а вы разве нет??оО

Comment: Во первых одна точка входа не всегда удобна и оправдана - это факт<br>
@dogmar - конечно можно без zf и тому подобных фреймворков, если вы можете себе позволить(в смысле уровня квалификации) - наваяйте себе свою структуру банальную, просто грубо говоря свой MVC очень легкий фреймворк задача которого будет тупо реализовывать FrontController+MVC, лично у меня, в свое время на это ушло пара часов(по ходу конечно чето дописывалось нередко, но на основу где-то так)<br><br>
Не слушайте тех кто говорит что велосипеды - плохо, написав код вы станете в 100500 раз лучше понимать любой MVC фреймворк...

Answer (score 3):

Вот видео урок

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRacpbuG6Es

и сам сайт

http://mvcphp.ru/

Comment: Благодаря этому видео и автору - "роботу"(как он себя называет) я наконец то понял и сформировал для себя в уме что же такое MVC

Answer (score 0):

Взять готовый MVC фреймворк и разбираться как работает. CodeIgniter например